# Enlarging the table

Tags: tables, scaling

How to enlarge this table? Thank you in advance

```
\begin{table}[ht]
            \large
            \centering

            \begin{tabular}{c|c||*{8}{c|}}
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{j} \tabularnewline
                \cline{2-10}
                \multirow{9}*{\rotatebox{90}{i}} &  & \bfseries 0 & \bfseries 1 & \bfseries 2 & \bfseries 3 & \bfseries 4 & \bfseries 5 & \bfseries 6 & \bfseries 7  \tabularnewline[1 ex] 
                \cline{2-10} & \bfseries 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \tabularnewline [1ex] 
                \cline{2-10} & \bfseries 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\tabularnewline [1ex] 
                \cline{2-10} & \bfseries 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \tabularnewline [1ex] 
                \cline{2-10} & \bfseries 3 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 9 \tabularnewline [1ex] 
                \cline{2-10} & \bfseries 4 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 8 & \bfseries 9 \tabularnewline [1 ex]
                \cline{2-10}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
```

Comment: `\Large` or `\Huge`  instead of `\large`?

Comment: With `tabularx`?

Comment: Which dimension(s) are we talking about?

Comment: Change `8` to `9` for another column? Add a row?

Comment: I want to scaling the table. please help me

Comment: For the scaling, you can use \scalebox{} just before the tabular environment.

Comment: @Bernard. With tabularx environment, Huge is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \Huge
    \centering
    \scalebox{1.5}{ %This is for scaling.
    \begin{tabular}{c|c||*{8}{c|}}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{j} \tabularnewline
        \cline{2-10}
        \multirow{9}*{\rotatebox{90}{i}} &  & \bfseries 0 & \bfseries 1 & \bfseries 2 & \bfseries 3 & \bfseries 4 & \bfseries 5 & \bfseries 6 & \bfseries 7  \tabularnewline[1 ex] 
        \cline{2-10} & \bfseries 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \tabularnewline [1ex] 
        \cline{2-10} & \bfseries 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\tabularnewline [1ex] 
        \cline{2-10} & \bfseries 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \tabularnewline [1ex] 
        \cline{2-10} & \bfseries 3 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 9 \tabularnewline [1ex] 
        \cline{2-10} & \bfseries 4 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 8 & \bfseries 9 \tabularnewline [1 ex]
        \cline{2-10}
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

For enlarging the table, change large to huge. Furthermore, for the scaling purpose, you can use \scalebox{} just before the tabular environment. Hope this helps.

Comment: you have a space within the scalebox to the left and right of the table, be careful where you need `%` at ends of lines.